# Windows 10 Miracast while using mobile hotspot

Tags: windows-10, miracast

I was trying to use Miracast (the Windows 10 screen projection feature) on my laptop to connect to my desktop PC at home.

It's working if I connect both PCs to my WiFi, however the WiFi quality in this room is not great.

Since my desktop PC has both wireless adapter and a LAN connection, I am trying to use my desktop PC as a hotspot and share the LAN internet connection with my laptop. This works great with the built-in mobile hotspot functionality in Windows 10!

However, now I'm no longer able to use the Miracast feature. The laptop is connected to the new hotspot from the desktop PC and the internet connection is working. But I can no longer see my PC when I try projecting from my laptop.

Is there any way to make Miracast work with mobile hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

Your hotspot is a completely different network from your home network, so this is not going to work.

Try getting your network to the location you want.

Use powerline Ethernet to do this, or plain Ethernet, as these are likely the easiest thing to do.Then add wireless in your location. Hook it up on the same subnet.

This way you can use Miracast.

Comment: Technically Miracast should not need the two devices being in the same network though, since they form their own peer-to-peer / WiFi direct connection.

Comment: Thanks John. I already have an Ethernet connection to my desktop PC.
Will it work if I get another WiFi dongle and plug it in to my desktop PC? (ie. my desktop PC will have Ethernet and 2 WiFi: 1 as a hotspot (sharing the Ethernet internet connection) and another to connect to the main WiFi just for the miracast)

Comment: Will it work if I get another WiFi dongle and plug it in to my desktop PC?  <-- It might work. I am not sure with Miracast if distance is involved.  I was responding to your post   "It's working if I connect both PCs to my WiFi, however the WiFi quality in this room is not great."